# Writing a C++ vector to an output file

Tags: c++, file-io, vector, formatting

```
ofstream outputFile ("output.txt");

if (outputFile.is_open())
{
     outputFile << "GLfloat vector[]={" <<  copy(vector.begin(), vector.end(), ostream_iterator<float>(cout, ", ")); << "}" << endl;
}
else cout << "Unable to open output file";
```

How do I output a vector to a file, with each float separated by commas? I would also like to avoid printing square brackets if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
outputFile << "GLfloat vector[]={";
copy(vector.begin(), vector.end(), ostream_iterator<float>(outputFile , ", ")); 
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^
outputFile << "}" << endl;
```

Comment: it would be awesome to get an explanation of what you've done, in addition to the code.

Answer (score 3):

First, you shouldn't call your variable `vector`. Give it a name which is not the name of a class from the Standard Library.

Secondly, `ostream_iterator` will append a `','` even after the last element of the vector, which may not be what you want (a separator should be a *separator*, and there's nothing to separate the last value of the vector from a further value).

In C++11, you could use a simple range-based `for` loop:

```
outputFile << "GLfloat vector[]={";
auto first = true;
for (float f : v) 
{ 
    if (!first) { outputFile << ","; } 
    first = false; 
    outputFile << f; 
}
outputFile << "}" << endl;
```

In C++03, it is going to be just a bit more verbose:

```
outputFile << "GLfloat vector[]={";
auto first = true;
for (vector<float>::iterator i = v.begin(); i != end(); ++i) 
{ 
    if (!first) { outputFile << ","; c++; } 
    first = false;
    outputFile << *i;
}
outputFile << "}" << endl;
```

Comment: Think you got that for loop mixed up.

Comment: No problem. Is it okay if I ask: Why haven't you been answering questions lately?

Comment: @0x499602D2: I have a lot of work to do and some health issues that forced me to re-prioritize my activity on SO, but I plan to get back soon :)

Comment: Best of luck. I hope everything gets better for you. :)

Comment: @AndyProwl Shouldn't the 'c++' be outside of the if block? If not, c would never increase from 0.

Also, perhaps a bool would be a better option than using an int.

Comment: @user19448: Indeed, that was an oversight. I edited the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You've taken the solution and attempted to stick it into the stream insertion. That's not how it works. It should be a separate line:

```
outputFile << "GLfloat vector[]={";
copy(vector.begin(), vector.end(), ostream_iterator<float>(outputFile, ", "));
outputFile << "}" << endl;
```

The `copy` algorithm simply copies elements from one range to another. `ostream_iterator` is a special iterator that will actually insert (with `<<`) into the given stream when you do `*it = item_to_insert;`.

Comment: It still says copy_n is not declared, despite including all the following:

`#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h> `

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice generic (header-only) library, which you just need to include in your code and it will allow you to print any standard containers easily: http://louisdx.github.com/cxx-prettyprint/